# Why does the AngularJS view not update with new array?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

When a variable is updated with new results from the AWS SDK by pressing the "Test AWS Credentials" the view should update the list below the create model textbox; however it does not. The model list (below the create model textbox) also stops working when trying to create new models using the textbox. What is causing these issues?

AWS SDK will return a result like... `{"TableNames":["Manufactures","Restaurants","Nutrition"]}`

A demo can be seen here: http://bghtrbb.github.io/AWS-API-Generator/app/index.html

The source code is here: http://github.com/bghtrbb/AWS-API-Generator

If you need test credentials you can use these

Access Key ID:
AKIAJPEZZAC77Y7TPADA

Secret Access Key:
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

Here is the controller for the Test AWS Credentials Button

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("awsCredentialsTester", function($scope, apiGenerator)
{
    $scope.AwsCredentials = {
        apiKey: '',
        apiSecret: ''
    };
    $scope.testAwsCredentials = function()
    {
        AWS.config.update({
            accessKeyId: $scope.AwsCredentials.apiKey,
            secretAccessKey: $scope.AwsCredentials.apiSecret
        });
        AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

        var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
        dynamodb.listTables({}, function(err, data)
        {
            if (err)
            {
                console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                swal("Oh No!", err + "<br/>" + err.stack, "error");

                AWS.config.update({
                    accessKeyId: "",
                    secretAccessKey: ""
                });
            }
            else
            {
                apiGenerator.apiKey = $scope.AwsCredentials.apiKey;
                apiGenerator.apiSecret = $scope.AwsCredentials.apiSecret;
                apiGenerator.changeModelList(data.TableNames);

                console.log(data); // successful response
                swal("Success!", JSON.stringify(data), "success");
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Here is the apiGenerator Factory

```
angular.module('app').factory("apiGenerator", function () {
    var apiGenerator = {};

    apiGenerator.apiKey = "";
    apiGenerator.apiSecret = "";

    apiGenerator.models = [];
    apiGenerator.resources = [];

    apiGenerator.addNewModel = function (newModelName) {
        apiGenerator.models.push(newModelName);
        1+1;
    };

    apiGenerator.changeModelList = function (newModelList) {
        apiGenerator.models = newModelList;
        1+1;
    };

    return apiGenerator;
});
```

Here is the directive for the model list

```
angular.module('app').directive("modelOverview", ['apiGenerator', function(apiGenerator)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope:  true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.modelOverview = {
                newModelName: "",
                models: []
            };

            scope.$watch("models", function (models) {
                scope.modelOverview.models = apiGenerator.models;
            });

            scope.addNewModel = function () {
                apiGenerator.addNewModel(scope.modelOverview.newModelName);
                scope.modelOverview.newModelName = "";
            };

            element.bind("keypress", function (event) {
                if(event.which === 13) {
                    scope.addNewModel();
                }
            });
        },
        templateUrl: 'assets/components/model_overview/model_overview_directive_template.html'
    };
}]);
```

And finally here is the directive template

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><span>Create Model:</span></div>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="modelOverview.newModelName">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" ng-click="addNewModel()" >Go!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <ul class="list-group" id="model-list">
        <li class="list-group-item"  ng-repeat="model in modelOverview.models"><span> {{model}} </span></li>
    </ul>
    <span>{{modelOverview.models}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be some issue with the new array being assigned AngularJS messes up.
To get around this I have changed `apiGenerator.changeModelList()` function to...

```
apiGenerator.changeModelList = function (newModelList) {
        apiGenerator.models.splice(0, apiGenerator.models.length);
        Array.prototype.push.apply(apiGenerator.models, newModelList);
    };
```

And called `$scope.$apply();` where the `apiGenerator.changeModelList(data.TableNames);` is called in the controller.

It is now working properly but if anyone else can suggest a different(/better) fix I would like to hear it.